# How to source stdout in bash?

Tags: python, bash, macos, environment-variables

I am having trouble exporting environmental variables from stdout.

What do I do wrong and how to fix it?

```
$ cat env.py 
print("export TEST_ME=123")

$ python env.py
export TEST_ME=123

$ echo $(python env.py)
export TEST_ME=123

$ echo $(python env.py) | . /dev/fd/0
bash: echo: write error: Broken pipe

$ echo "export TEST_ME=123" | . /dev/fd/0 && echo $TEST_ME

$
```

Same command works in zsh

```
$ zsh
% echo "export TEST_ME=123" | . /dev/fd/0 && echo $TEST_ME
123
%
```

**Update:**

Python3.9 on macOS gets that broken pipe, so I am trying with just echo

```
$ bash --noprofile --norc
bash-3.2$ . <(echo "export TEST_ME=123") && echo $TEST_ME

bash-3.2$ . <(python3.9 env.py)
bash-3.2$ Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

bash-3.2$ . <(python2 env.py)
bash-3.2$ close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr

bash-3.2$
```

Comment: `source <(python ./env.py); declare -p TEST_ME`

Comment: I'm not getting the `Broken pipe` error for that command. In any case the `echo` is pointless; `python env.py | . /dev/fd/0` should be at least as good, and has fewer escaping troubles.

Comment: `source <(echo export TEST_ME=456); declare -p TEST_ME`

Comment: `source <(printf 'export TEST_ME=789'); declare -p TEST_ME`

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/272487

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use process substitution:

```
$ . <(python env.py)
$ echo $TEST_ME
123
```

The way this works is: it creates a temporary pipe in the filesystem, and connects stdout of `python env.py` to the pipe. The `<(...)` construct itself is then replaced by the file name of that pipe.

Comment: I get that broken pipe for my python3.9 on macOS, but can it at least work for echo? This does not: ` . <(echo "export TEST_ME=123") && echo $TEST_ME`

Comment: Updated question with the command and its output

Comment: working in macOS: `eval "$(echo "export TEST_ME=123")" && echo $TEST_ME`

Comment: Isn't it strange that eval is needed for macOS?

Comment: I don't know; process substitution works also on macOS in other cases. Maybe its a bash 3.2 thing